# UI Grid - Expand Row add empty space in bottom

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, expand, ui-grid

Using angularJs UI Grid plugin, [Docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20216%20Expandable%20grid)

While expanding the last row, sometimes empty spaces is added in the bottom[image]

Comment: I am also able to recreate this on their docs page in Chrome. You may want to just open an issue with them on the [github repository](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues)

Comment: Thanks Mark, opened one in github [Issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/7151)